# How to interpolate the GPS readings in the real time in java

Tags: java, android, gps, interpolation

I am trying to build a real-time car monitoring application using Android. The cars would appear on the map with their current position. The problem is that the updating of the position via the GPS is slow. So the solution that was suggested for that is to use interpolation, and get the missing coordinates until the GPS updates the position. All proposed solutions I found need us to have two GPS coordinates points to interpolate between them, but since I am trying to work in the real time, I only have the initial GPS coordinates to add up to. Can anyone help in how I could achieve this? Or is there any other proposed method I could use?

Comment: I do not get it, if it is real time you can have a lot of the previous positions stored? Maybe not for the very first update, but from then on..

Comment: yes but I can not get the next position and interpolate between it and my current position for smooth animation on the map @cYrixmorten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you're going to have to calculate the average speed at which the vehicle was going from the previous two positions (distance/time, preferably meters/s). From that, you can construct a vector and add it to the most current position vector, multiplying it by itself every second between the next update. Simple pseudo-code below:

```
prevPos = vector
currentPos = vector

prevPosTime = time
currentPosTime = time

speed = ((currentPos - prevPos).magnitude) / (currentPosTime - prevPosTime)

waitingtime = 0
until currentPos change:
    assumedLocation = currentPos + ((currentPos - prevPos).normalized * speed * waitingtime)
    wait(1s)
    waitingtime += 1
```

I know it's incredibly basic, but I hope you get the gist of where I'm going with this.

Edit -- Just more explanation as to what I'm blabbering on about

`(currentPos - prevPos).normalized` this is the last known DIRECTION of the vehicle. This can be scaled by multiplying it by any value

`(currentPos - prevPos).magnitude` this is the last known SPEED. We can't use the normalized vector for this because normalizing 'removes' any scaling. We are basically just calculating how big the vector is and that's our speed.

`currentPos + ((currentPos - prevPos).normalized * speed * waitingtime)` this adds to the vector from the current pos by the direction multiplied by the speed which is again multiplied by the time since the last update. You end up with a prediction of where the car should be based on the previous speed and direction of travel

Suggested edit:
Important note, this is prediction, not interpolation. We would be using interpolation if we knew both values, however since one is unknown we are using prediction.

Comment: I understand this so far, but what do you mean by normalized here '(currentPos - prevPos).normalized'

Comment: Okay so the normalized version of a vector is a vector with a magnitude of 1. I can be calculated as follows (first we need then length): `length = sqrt(vector.x^2 + vector.y^2)` `normal = new vector(vector.x / length, vector.y / length)`

Comment: Video linked in case you want a more detailed explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fn03DIW3Ak

Comment: @Polymer you might want to explain how we're using prediction instead of interpolation. Could be more usefull for future readers

Comment: @prog, if you've accepted my answer, would be grateful if you were to accept my answer :) Or Thijs Steel's answer, whatever helped more

Answer (score 0):

Polymer has a great answer using linear prediction. However, there are some better prediction methods if you need them.

What i would use is Double Exponential Smoothing. This will not only take the previous positions into account, but also all the other positions.

If your GPS can also give the precision of each detection, you can use a kalman filter. Not an easy filter, but a really good one.